# Relacionamento Laravel 5.2 Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent, laravel-blade

Bom dia pessoal,

Estou tendo um problema num relacionamento entre tabelas com Elouquent (Laravel)

Tenho duas tabelas [clientes / atividades_comerciais] (innoDB MYSQL)

Na tabela cliente tem um campo (FK) chamado: atividades_comerciais_id
Na tabela atividades_comerciais tem o campo index: id, juntamente com o campo atividade_comercial (varchar)

No momento em que tento recuperar as informações do cliente, gostaria que viesse junto aos campos a atividade comercial e seu id relacionado a esse cliente.

Estou fazendo da seguinte maneira no Controller:

```
$return = \App\Cliente::find($id)->with('atividadesComerciais')->get();
return view('clientes.show', ['data'=>$return]);
```

No Model:

```
public function atividadesComerciais()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\AtividadesComerciais', 'atividades_comerciais_id', 'id');
    }
```

Antes eu conseguia acessar as informações na view pelo blade assim

```
{{ $data['razao_nome'] }}
```

mas agora não é possível.

Onde posso está errando ?

Answer (score 2):

Os relacionamentos belongsTo do `Laravel` são armazenados numa propriedade da instância do seu Model. Essa propriedade será sempre o nome do método relacionamento.

Por exemplo, se seu model `User` relaciona com `Role`, através do método `User::role`, teríamos o seguinte:

```
class User {
     public function role() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
     }
}
```

Para você poderá acessar os dados do relacionamento, seria da seguinte forma:

```
$user = User::with('role')->find($id);

$user->role->name; // admin
$user->role->id; // 3
$user->name; // Wallace de Souza
```

Ou seja, o Laravel converterá o nome do seu método do relacionamento em uma propriedade, que tratá os valores relacionamentos, caso existirem.

Há algumas observações importante a se fazer:

```
\App\Cliente::find($id)->with('atividadesComerciais')->get();
```

Você colocou o `with` depois de `find`. No Laravel isso faz toda a diferença, já que `find` é um método do `Eloquent Builder`, e `with` é um método estático de `Model` - que por sua vez retorna uma nova instância do próprio model. Sendo assim, para obter o comportamento desejado, você deve usar o `with` sempre que for iniciar qualquer consulta, para carregar os relacionamentos "ansiosamente".

Veja:

```
 \App\Cliente::with('atividadesComerciais')->find(1);
```

Se você deseja carregar o relacionamento após ter feito a consulta, você usará, na verdade, o método `load`.

Exemplo:

```
$user = User::find(1);

$user->load('role');

$user->role->id; // 3
```

Comment: Estou com problema com relacionamentos, fiz o que você explicou mas o problema persistiu. A propriedade do Relacionamento vem sempre vazia.

Comment: Mas qual é o problema?

Comment: Tenho um relacionamento N pra N entre áreas e cursos. Busco uma área especifica e utilizo '$area->cursos' e sempre retorna vazio

Answer (score 1):

Você está finalizando com o método `get()`, isso resulta em uma coleção de modelos. Tente alterar de:

```
$return = \App\Cliente::find($id)->with('atividadesComerciais')->get();
```

para

```
$return = \App\Cliente::with('atividadesComerciais')->find($id);
```

Dessa forma com o método `find()` retornamos um único modelo. Se preferir, pode deixar o método `get()`, mas na view você deve utilizar dessa forma:

```
@foreach ($data as $model)
    {{ $model->razao_nome }}
@endforeach
```